# Can I compile Java into shared library(.so) and load it by System.load() function in Java?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

Can I compile java into shared library(.so) and load it by System.load() function in Java? The reason why I want to do this is that I do not want other people can reverse my java code. I want to keep some java code secret.

Any suggestion is appreciated! If it is feasible, can you give me an example?Thanks a lot!

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Research ‘Java obfuscation’ instead.

Comment: *I do not want other people can reverse my java code*  Then don't give them your implementation.  If you distribute your compiled binaries, whoever you give them to will be able to reverse your code.  All obfuscation does is make that task somewhat harder to do.  Your code still has to *do* what it's designed to do, and what it *does* is easily observable no matter how "obfuscated" it may be.  Why do you think someone would want to bother reversing your code?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I just want to escape the static analysis.Any way, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Biffen Roger that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not trivial to make Java code executable but not possible to reverse engineer, and I would recommend against such a technical solution.

You typically have two options:

- Enforce the "You must not reverse engineer my code" in the license. In other words make it a political and not technical solution.  This typically works best for paying clients.
- Have the code you need to be secret elsewhere.  A typical way to do this is to have your program invoke the secret code through webservices on a server you control.

For Java the Jersey JAX-RS implementation works well for us.